# XPath find element based on ancestor element

Tags: java, xml, xpath, abstract-syntax-tree

again I have Java AST which is created from

```
public class Test  {
     String o = new String("hh");
     public void wrong1() {
       synchronized(o) {
             // huhu
      }
   }
}
```

I try to create a XPath query which finds the synchronized block in which the defined String variable `o` is used.

As the definition is above it is an ancestor of the SynchronizedStatement, but I dont get it working

```
//SynchronizedStatement[Expression/PrimaryExpression/PrimaryPrefix/Name[@Image=ancestor::ClassOrInterfaceBody[ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration/FieldVariableDeclaratorId/@Image]]]
```

I know that `/SynchronizedStatement[Expression/PrimaryExpression/PrimaryPrefix/Name[@Image=` is correct, my problem is how to address the ancestor ClassOrInterfaceBody part.

Hope its clear what i mean ;-)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To test that the two @Image are the same.

```
//SynchronizedStatement[ Expression/PrimaryExpression/PrimaryPrefix/Name/@Image = ancestor::ClassOrInterfaceBody/ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration/FieldVariableDeclaratorId/@Image ]
```

To also test for String type, assuming that FieldDeclaration and FieldVariableDeclaratorId have a common attribute (name).

```
//SynchronizedStatement[
    Expression/PrimaryExpression/PrimaryPrefix/Name/@Image = 
    ancestor::ClassOrInterfaceBody/ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration/FieldVariableDeclaratorId[
        @name = ancestor::ClassOrInterfaceBody/ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration/FieldDeclaration[Type/ReferenceType/ClassOrInterfaceType/@Image = 'String']/@name
    ]/@Image
]
```

If the @Image from the original XPath is "String":

```
//SynchronizedStatement[ Expression/PrimaryExpression/PrimaryPrefix/Name/@Image = ancestor::ClassOrInterfaceBody/ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration/FieldVariableDeclaratorId/@Image[. = 'String'] ]
```

Comment: thanks for that - that works.

But another problem - basically I want to check that the two @Image are the same, BUT only if the variable is a String.

so Object o = new Object(); should not match... 

how can I combine these two conditions a) the @Image check and that the found ancestor element also is of type String.

I know how to check if its a String, but not how to combine to searches (that they are working on the SAME node).

THANKS

Comment: @martymcfly What is the test for String type, and on what node?

Comment: basically in the ancestor as above.

pseudo like

the image is compared to 

`ancestor:ClassOrInterfaceBody/ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration/FieldDeclaration/VariableDeclarator/VariableDeclaratorId/@Image`
 
and the String comparison is made on that ancestor

`ancestor::ClassOrInterfaceBody/ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration/FieldDeclaration/Type/ReferenceType/ClassOrInterfaceType[@Image='String']`

so basically the `FieldDeclaration` is the node which contains the information about String and the Name. But `ClassOrInterfaceBody` is the common ancestor for this and the Synchron.Statements

Comment: thanks for the answer again.

But I need in both ancestor calls exactly the SAME ancestor. This XPath also validates true if there is any other FieldDeclaration which is a String, not exclusively the one also in the synchronized block.

Comment: @martymcfly We need to be able to find a FieldDeclaration from a FieldVariableDeclaratorId. Is there a FieldDeclaration/@Id ?

Comment: the hierarchy is
ClassOrInterfaceBody -> ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration -> FieldDeclaration -> Type | VariableDeclarator -> VariableDeclaratorId.

So no FieldVariableDeclaratorId.

on the level of ClassOrInterfaceBody there are several ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration, one contains the Field information and one contains the Sync. information

Comment: to your question:
no they dont have any attribute in common, they are "only" directly related. as one is the child of the other